# Getting error in sql query "The column 'nextid' was specified multiple times"

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am getting an error when executing this SQL query:

> The column 'nextid' is specified multiple times

It is working fine in SQL Server but when I try to run the query on Azure Data flow as source query, I get the error.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN bp.nextid IS NULL 
          THEN 
             CASE 
                WHEN nextid = '100000' THEN '100000' 
                WHEN nextid = '300000' THEN '300000' 
                WHEN nextid = '400000' THEN '400000' 
                   THEN '500000' 
                ELSE '500000' 
             END 

       WHEN bp.nextid IS NOT NULl 
          THEN bp.nextid    
    END 'LastBudgetPoolId',  
    * 
FROM 
    staging.nextid bp 
LEFT JOIN 
    staging.gca ga ON bp.next id = ga.nextid;
```

Comment: Don't use `*`, specify your columns. Clearly both tables have the column `nextid`. And of course it'll error as a source. How do you referrence `nextid` when it appears more than once? Your column names need to be **unique**.

Comment: Thanks! its working

Comment: @ZCoder hi,ZCoder. Would you please summarize Larnu's solution as an answer to end this case?That will be helpful for community members.

Answer (score 0):

As @larnu said that don't use `*` so I change the query and added column names after that working fine as

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN bp.nextid IS NULL 
          THEN 
             CASE 
                WHEN nextid = '100000' THEN '100000' 
                WHEN nextid = '300000' THEN '300000' 
                WHEN nextid = '400000' THEN '400000' 
                   THEN '500000' 
                ELSE '500000' 
             END 

       WHEN bp.nextid IS NOT NULl 
          THEN bp.nextid    
    END 'LastBudgetPoolId',  
    id,name,username ,nextid
FROM 
    staging.nextid bp 
LEFT JOIN 
    staging.gca ga ON bp.next id = ga.nextid;
```

Comment: I'm still cringing, and surprised it's still not complaining about this part: 
`WHEN nextid = '100000' THEN '100000'  ... WHEN nextid = '300000' THEN '300000' ... WHEN nextid = '400000' THEN '400000' ... as `
WHICH nextid is that pulling from?